# Pull Instagram images into an existing loop?

Tags: wp-query, loop, images

I am looking for a solution to pull Instagram images (from a single account) into a Wordpress loop and mix them chronologically with standard posts that will have been created within the Wordpress admin.

So the archive page would be a mix of news items (full posts) and Instagram images, all in the same feed, appearing chronologically from whenever they were posted.

Is that possible (with or without a plugin)?

Thanks in advance for your response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that I was able to do this by using the Instagrate Pro plugin, which creates individual posts for every image it pulls in from Instagram. The standard loop then just pulls in those posts into the archive.